# how to join two files and replace wrong values in a variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

Good morning I have a file with some incorrect values for some variables, and I must replace them with correct values with a second file

```
file 1:
city lat       log 
Bog  5°3'33sS  05°34'3,4w
Bog  8°3'44sS  07°78'4,6w
Cal  51°3'3sS  45°34'3,4w
Bog  22°3'12sS 05°34'3,4w
Cal  13°3'44sS 07°78'4,6w
Cal  64°3'3sS  45°34'3,4w
```

file 2 (correct file)

```
city lat            log 
Bog  4°35'56.57N  74°04'51''3W
Cal  3°42'158N      76°31′14″W
```

The idea is to replace the incorrect values of the LAT and LONG columns of file 1 with file 2, i am ussing join, but join increase the columns, it could eliminate the previous ones, but it is quite cumbersome for a n files.

I know the answer is in join command (possible) but I can't figure out how to join can be use to correct

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that row in file-1 is correct if there is no matching row in file-2.

Then, for the example you have given, this can be done in two stages: (1) removing wrong rows from file-1, (2) appending the rows from file-2.

```r
f1_no_wrong = file1 %>%
  anti_join(file2, by = "city")

appended = rbind(f1_no_wrong, f2)
```

An anti-join returns every row in the LHS that does not match a record in the RHS.

Note that the above approach will fail if file-1 or file-2 contain different columns from each other (e.g. there are some other columns in file-1, not included in your example above, that you want to preserve).

In this case I would recommend something like:

```r
joined = f1 %>%
  left_join(f2, by = "city", suffix = c("","_true")) %>%
  mutate(final_lat = ifelse(is.na(lat_true), lat, lat_true), # keep true value if exists
         final_log = ifelse(is.na(log_true), log, log_true)) %>%
  select(-lat, -log, -lat_true, -log_true) %>% # discard finished with columns
  rename(lat = lat_true, log = log_true) %>%
  distinct() # optional, may be required if duplicate wrong values
```